# How can I calculate a hover state change based on the original state values?

Tags: css, image, hover, padding, margin

This may not be possible using just CSS alone buuuut let's give her a whirl.

**For example:** I have an image with certain margins. let's say something like this:

```
img {
margin-left: 1em;
}
```

What I want to do, (I'll write it in pseudo code) is something like this:

```
img:hover {
margin-left: [take original non-hover state margin, then -1 from that to make 0]
}
```

Hopefully I'm making sense here if it's even possible - I've really tried to simplify that example down.

Comment: **take** *original non-hover state margin*, is not possible,wish for *css 4* to provide those features.

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
margin-left: 1em;
}
img:hover {
margin-right: 1em;// for minus 1
}
```

## you can use `margin-right` to subract

> P.S remember what you learnt in childhood about *net force*